# understanding when to use left right rules sequent calculus

Tags: sequent-calculus

I'm trying to understand this classical Sequent Calculus proof.

[image]

These are the rules Of Sequent Calculus(version 1) in respect to this question
[image] [image]

How do we know to use `[v R2]` and `[v R1]` instead of `[v L]` which I originally used

and also on why we know to use `[v R2]` on `A⊢(A→B) ∨ (B→A)` and `[v R1]` on `¬A⊢(A→B) ∨ (B→A)`  and not the other way around.

Comment: The rule $\lor L$ needs the same formula (called $C$ in the rule) on the right side of $\vdash$ in both premises. At the stages where the proof used $\lor R_1$ and $\lor R_2$, the right sides of the premises were different ($B\to A$ and $A\to B$), so $\lor L$ couldn't be applied.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thankyou, but now how do we know whether to use ∨R1 or ∨R2

Comment: Which $\lor R$ rule to use is determined by the fact that you want the final conclusion to be $(A\to B)\lor(B\to A)$ rather than $(B\to A)\lor(A\to B)$.